# arguments object in child function (works on chrome console but not elsewhere)

Tags: javascript, arguments, strict

I'm working through the exercise "[Seek and Destroy](https://www.freecodecamp.com/challenges/seek-and-destroy/)" from Free Code Camp. Any arguments following the first one which is the array should be filtered from the array.

I came up with this code which works on chrome console:

```
function destroyer(arr) {

  return arr.filter(function(x){
    for(var i = 1; i < destroyer.arguments.length; i++){
      if(x == destroyer.arguments[i]) {return false;}
    }
    return true;
  });

}

destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3); //should return [1, 1]
```

On JS Bin and other places it doesn't do anything as it is. Only if I use console.log with a new array instead of return only, it will work. When I run it in Free Code Camp I get:

> TypeError: 'caller' and 'arguments' are restricted function properties
>   and cannot be accessed in this context.

I have found that this may have to do with strict mode. But what does it actually mean? Is this saying that I cannot use the arguments object of the parent function inside the child function?

I can make it work everywhere if I convert the arguments into an array first and then use that array in the child function. But I'm curious why having the arguments in the child function does work in the chrome console but not elsewhere, and whether there's a way to use arguments object in the child function.

Comment: Doesn't answer your question about why it works in the console, but note that if you make the inner function an ES6 arrow function then it can access the `arguments` object of the outer function: https://jsfiddle.net/aa66x552/, though if you're going to use ES6 syntax you can avoid `arguments` altogether by using rest parameters instead: https://jsfiddle.net/aa66x552/1/ - or even: `function destroyer(arr, ...vals) { return arr.filter(x => vals.indexOf(x) === -1); }`.

Answer (score 1):

[Strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) is a special mode of JavaScript in which a lot of features you shouldn't be using aren't allowed. Among these features is accessing the `arguments` or `caller` properties of a function, like you are doing with `destroyer.arguments`, which is why you're getting an error when you try to do this in strict mode.

Instead, you should access `arguments` as a special variable in the outer function, and assign it to a variable:

```js
// use strict mode
"use strict";

function destroyer(arr) {
  // assign arguments to a variable that can be accessed by the inner
  // function
  var destroyerArguments = arguments;

  return arr.filter(function(x){
    // use destroyerArguments instead of destroyer.arguments
    for(var i = 1; i < destroyerArguments.length; i++){
      if(x == destroyerArguments[i]) {return false;}
    }
    return true;
  });
}

console.log(destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3)); // prints [ 1, 1 ]
```

Note that *by default* strict mode isn't enabled, so when you're running your code in Chrome's console, these features are not disallowed. However, Free Code Camp probably enables strict mode automatically, so you have to design your code accordingly. You can enable strict mode yourself by adding the line

```
"use strict";
```

to the top of your function or file, as I have done in the code above.

Comment: I had done this as well actually. Was just trying to figure out if it was somehow possible to access the arguments from within the inner function. I guess the reason it's not possible is because by using destroyer.arguments would mean that arguments would be a property of destroyer, which it is not?

Comment: @slacle There *is* a function property `arguments` defined on the function; it's just [decprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/arguments) and not recommended to be used, and therefore you're not allowed to use it in strict mode. Declaring a variable in the outer function, like I did in the example, is the way you should do it if you want to access the arguments of the outer function.